# getting string of data within a file, loop untill all instances are found

Tags: vb.net, loops, streamreader

I have a bit of vb.net code that will search for a string, then get a certain amount of characters after it and display in within a text box.

My issue is that is some cases there are more than one string of text I need to display, so rather than just searching for "name" once, how can I loop through the file and display a list of all instances?

This is the code I am using now.

```
Public Sub readAddress()

    Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(profile + "\Desktop\" + dir + "\" + newfile + ".dat")
    Dim data = sr.ReadToEnd()
    Dim pos = data.IndexOf("name")
    If pos >= 0 Then
        ListBox1.Text = data.Substring(pos, 39).Replace("name""", "") + Environment.NewLine
    End If
    sr.Close()
    txt()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim FILE_NAME As String = sr
Dim TextLine As String
If System.IO.File.Exists( FILE_NAME ) = True Then
    Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)
    Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
        TextLine = TextLine & objReader.ReadLine() & vbNewLine
    Loop
    ListBox1.Text = TextLine
Else
    MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
End If
```

This piece of coding might help you

Answer (score 0):

Consider using regular expressions:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Sub readAddress()
    Dim fileText = File.ReadAllText(profile + "\Desktop\" + dir + "\" + newfile + ".dat")
    Dim matches = Regex.Matches(fileText,"name")

    For Each m In matches
        'The call to Substring will return 10 characters after each instance of "name"
        Listbox1.Text += Environment.NewLine & fileText.Substring(m.Index + 4,10)
    Next

    'Instead of the For Each loop, use LINQ, and String.Join
    Listbox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, matches.Select(Function(m) fileText.Substring(m.Index + 4,10)))
End Sub
```